# How does Gzip / mod_deflate affect crawlers / spiders / robots (ultimately also my seo)?

Tags: seo, gzip, mod-deflate

I've been tasked to look into Gzip compression. I've figured out so far that is not just generally accepted, but also pretty common. Now my question is how does Gzip compression influence the crawlers that visit my page?

What should I keep in mind when I decide to Gzip my page?

Will my SEO suffer from this in any way?

In short, compression: How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Gzipping should not affect how crawlers look at the page. Google even suggests compressing the content, so there should not be any problem in using gzipped contents. In fact it should help in your page ranking. Most of the modern browsers supports Gzipped contents and request them in accept-headers. There are certain things you need to do like minifying of js and css before doing gzipping and there are plenty of good articles about what needs to be done. It also depends on your capability of your system environment.

**Caution**: There might be few region specific crawlers which may not support them, but most of the major ones do.

Comment: some browsers have issues with gzipping. this: header('Transfer-Encoding: gzip'); is supposed to fix things. where should I put that line?

Comment: I have not played around with content-encoding or transfer-encoding. So i don't want to give incorrect answer. The approach also depends on your system environment. I hope i answered your questions about the SEO. I could not help much on encoding part of it.

Comment: `Google even suggests compressing the content` source please. Thanks